# Django Form Data Does Not Save to DB (sqlite)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

When I submit the form my terminal says:  "POST /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 200 851.  When I check through python manage.py shell, the form data does not show up. I am not sure why the data is not saving to the db, which is sqlite.  I think the error is in the view section when I try to save the form.  I have read through different post, which seem to have similar issues, but I can't seem to figure out what my issue could be.

Model:

```
from django.db import models
class Stores(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s (%s,%s) %s" % (self.name, self.city, self.state, 
        self.address)
```

Forms:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from mysite.polls.models import Stores

   class StoreForm(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
           model = Stores
           fields = ['name','address','city','state']
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from mysite.polls.models import Stores
from mysite.polls.forms import StoreForm

def index(request):
    downtown_store = Stores.objects.get(name="Corporate")
    store_name = downtown_store.name
    store_address = downtown_store.address
    store_state = downtown_store.state
    if request.method == 'Post':
        form = StoreForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
               form.save(commit=True)
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
   else:
        form = StoreForm() 

       context = {'store_name':store_name, 'store_address':store_address, 'store_state':store_state, 'form':form,} 

       return render(request,'polls/index.html',context)
```

Templates:

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <h1> {{store_name}} </h1>
        <h2> {{store_address}} </h2>
        <h3> {{store_state}} </h3>

    <form action="{% url "index" %}"  method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

Comment: No, I was just testing how to pull data from the DB and display in a template.  Thanks for the information, good to know for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method needs to be in all caps.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Note, the last two lines of your view need to be moved one indent to the left.